# create mysql views with UNION operator on query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create sql view with a UNION operator on it. I tried executing the sql first before embedding it to the view and the result is success. But when I try it to embed on creating a view it returned this error

"Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
SELECT p.product_media_id AS media_id, p.product_title AS title, p.product' at line 8
"

I also assure that all columns have the same data type.

SQL view:

```
CREATE
/*[ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
[SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]*/
VIEW `mydbname`.`s_views` 
AS
(SELECT c.media_id AS media_id, 
    c.title AS title, 
    c.title_slug AS slug, 
    c.content_one      AS description, 
    c.type AS cat 
FROM content_content c 
WHERE c.type = 'news' 
    OR c.type='travel_genius' 
    AND c.media_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND c.status = 1
UNION
SELECT p.product_media_id AS media_id, 
    p.product_title AS title, 
    p.product_title_slug   AS slug, 
    p.product_description AS description, 
    'product' AS cat 
FROM p_views p
WHERE p.product_media_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: I am just using the format of sqlyog on creating views. And i've created a lot of views with parenthesis syntax succesfully

Comment: Did you try removing the parentheses to see if it will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in MySQL. It is the parenthesis that is triggering it:-

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21614

Comment: In 2015, and that bug still exists.